# Server sends response without fully receiving the request

Tags: http, browser, protocols, server

If browser sends big http request (file upload),
and server notices that the file is bigger than the server could handle.
The server sends some error message back without recieving the whole request.

Are all (or any) browsers able to read this server response, or they will wait with reading the response if they are not ready with sending the request?

http protocol is "request - response".

Does it mean the request **must** be completed before browser starts to wait for response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first line in an HTTP server response indicates whether the client request was successful or not, and why. The status is given with a three-digit server response code (also known as a status code) and a descriptive message.

Status codes are usually generated by Web servers, but they might also be generated by CGI scripts that bypass the server's precooked headers and supply their own. Status codes are grouped as follows:

Code Range  Response Meaning
100-199 Informational
200-299 Client request successful
300-399 Client request redirected, further action necessary
400-499 Client request incomplete
500-599 Server errors
HTTP defines only a few specific codes in each range, although servers may define their own as needed. If a client receives a code that it does not recognize, it should understand its basic meaning from its numerical range. While most Web browsers handle codes in the 100-, 200-, and 300- range silently, some error codes in the 400- and 500- range are commonly reported back to the user (e.g., "404 Not Found").

Comment: Sorry but it was not the question. It is all about sending respose to client during client sends request to server.

Comment: Hey it is mandatory to complete the request otherwise 400-499 Client request incomplete error will come in response

Comment: you can get response in parts but you can't send request in parts